# More extensive monitoring options for MSK serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, amazon-cloudwatch, jmx, aws-msk

As far as I've explored, the only metrics being provided by MSK serverless are `BytesInPerSec,BytesOutPerSec,FetchMessageConversionsPerSec,MaxEstimatedTimeLag,MaxOffsetLag,MessagesInPerSec,ProduceMessageConversionsPerSec,SumOffsetLag`

There is no mention of integration with Prometheus or even the JMX port exposed by the cluster in the serverless [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/serverless-monitoring.html)

I tried to fish for the size of the topic using on my EC2 client using `/bin/kafka-log-dirs.sh` but that resulted in an unsupported exception.

So, my question is is there any way to find deeper/extensive monitoring for my msk cluster or am I limited to what is mentioned in the docs?

Thanks.

Comment: Polling of JMX Mbeans requires a running server... There's several Cloudwatch Prometheus exporters, so what research have you done there?

Comment: There's no mention of the JMX server or the JMX exporter's ports for serverless. Also, the  metrics cloudwatch is currently providing for serverless are severely limited, which is why I've asked this question.

Comment: Like I said, there's no mention of JMX because that would imply there's a running JVM server available that exposes the JMX

Comment: If you need more metrics, ask MSK support team. Or don't use serverless. Dunno what else to say that's not already in the documentation